# Active Record: Joins query with "where" clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

this is my model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :author, :title
    validates :author, presence: true
    validates :title, :uniqueness => true, presence: true

    has_many :rentals 

    def rent?
        rentals.where(return_date: nil).count > 0
    end
end

class Rental < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :book

    validates :student, presence: true
    validates :book, presence: true
    validates :rental_date, presence: true

    attr_accessible :rental_date, :return_date, :student, :book

    def pending?
        return return_date == nil
    end

    def overdue?
        if(return_date)
            return_date - rental_date > 7.days
        else
            Time.now - rental_date > 7.days
        end
    end
end
```

I want to query all the books that are not in a rent (i.e. There's no rental for this book that doesn't have a return_date).

I thought I could use my "rent?" method, but I couldn't make it work, so I tried to make a join.

This is what I got:

```
Book.includes(:rentals).find(:all, :conditions => ['"rentals"."return_date" is NULL'])
```

But I also want to add some where queries based on my params.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

The `joins` method will work with left outer joins, but you'll need to construct the SQL fragment yourself. Below, this is demonstrated, combined with a `merge` and an additional a scope on Rental.

```
class Rental < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :no_return, where('return_date IS NULL')
end

join_statement = 'LEFT OUTER JOIN rentals ON rentals.book_id = books.id'
Book.joins(join_statement).merge(Rental.no_return)
# => returns set of books with no rentals and 
# books with rentals that have no return date
```

On an unrelated note, you'll find that many prefer to write your `pending?` method like so:

```
def pending?
  return_date.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `joins`:

```
Book.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN rentals ON books.id = rentals.book_id')
    .where('rentals.return_date IS NULL')
```

Comment: But using this way it would do a inner join, I need an outer join. So I can list every book that have rentals without return_date and books who have never been rent.

Comment: @DavidAnderson See my edit, you could use an outer join with `joins`.